# Prove convergence of this generalized integral

Tags: integration, logarithms

Prove the convergence of
$$\int_0^1 \left[\ln\left(1+\frac1x\right)\right]^a\mathrm dx$$
for $ a>0$.

Comment: Maybe I can compare $[ln(1+1/x)]^a$ with $1/x^b$ with $b>0$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Setting $1/x=y$, this is equal, up to a costant, to
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{\left(\ln(1+y)\right)^a}{y^2}\, \mathrm{d}y<<\int_1^\infty \frac{\sqrt{y}}{y^2}\mathrm{d}y,$$
which converges for all $a>0$.